# How do we prove that an interpretation A is isomorphic to itself?

Tags: logic

Prove that an A is isomorphic to A, where A is an interpretation.

So far I know that there is a correspondence from A to A via the identity function because $id(x) = x$ for every $x$. This proves condition $I_2$.

But how do I go about proving the rest of the conditions?

Interpretations $P$ and $Q$ are *isomorphic* if and only if there is a correspondence $j$ between the two and if the following conditions hold:

$I_1) \, \, R^P(p_1,...,p_n)$ if and only if $R^Q(j(p_1),...,j(p_n))$

$I_2) \, \, j(c^P) = c^Q$

$I_3) \, \, j(f^P(p_1,...,p_n)) = f^Q(j(p_1),...,j(p_n))$.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Math.SE. When it comes to making math readable, we like to use $\LaTeX$. Here's a quick guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Please use it to format your question.

Comment: Consider $I_1$ : $R^P(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ if and only if $R^Q(j(p_1),\ldots,j(p_n))$ ; in our case both $P$ and $Q$ are $A$ and the required mapping $j$ is $id$. Thus $I_1$ becomes : $R^A(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ if and only if $R^A(id(p_1),\ldots,id(p_n))=R^A(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ which obviously holds.

Answer (score 0):

The model theory bible by Chang and Keisler from 1973 defines two models $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{A}'$, or in your words interpretations, to be isomorphic iff there is a bijection $f$ mapping $A$ onto $A'$ (where $A$ and $A'$ are the domains of resp. $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{A}'$), satisfying the following conditions:

1. for each $n$-placed relation R of $\mathfrak{A}$ and the corresponding relation $R'$ of $\mathfrak{A}$: $R(a_1,.,..,a_n)$ iff $R'(f(a_1),..,f(a_n)$;
2. for each $m$-placed function $G$ on $\mathfrak{A}$ and the corresponding function $G'$ of $\mathfrak{A}'$: $f(G(a_1,...,a_m)) = G'(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$;
3. for each constant $c$ of $\mathfrak{A}$ and the corresponding constant $c'$ of $\mathfrak{A}'$: $f(c) = c'$.

This definition is clearly equivalent to your definition. Now define a function $f: A \rightarrow A$, s.t. for every $a_i \in A$, $a_i \mapsto a_i$. Clearly $f$ is then the identity function, which is a bijective function. So we just need to check the three conditions.

1. Let $R(a_1,...,a_n)$ be some $n$-placed relation $R$ of $\mathfrak{A}$. We have $a_i = f(a_i)$ for all $a_i \in R$, hence $R(a_1,...,a_n) = R(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$, so we have $R(a_1,...,a_n)$ iff $R(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$.
2. Let $G(a_1,...,a_m)$ be some $m$-placed function $G$ on $\mathfrak{A}$. We have $a_i = f(a_i)$ for all elements of $A$, so also $a_i = f(a_i)$ for all arguments $a_i$ of $G$, hence $G(a_1,...,a_m) = G(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$. Now $G(a_1,...,a_m)=a_j$ for some element $a_j \in A$, so $G(a_1,...,a_m) = G(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))=a_j=f(a_j)$. From this we can conclude that $f(G(a_1,...,a_m)) = f(a_j) = G(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$.
3. Let $c$ be some constant of $\mathfrak{A}$, that means that some constant $c^\mathcal{L}$ of our language $\mathcal{L}$ is interpreted by an element $a_i \in A$, which we denote by $c$. We have $a_i = f(a_i)$ for all elements of $A$, hence we have $c = f(c)$.

From the foregoing we can conclude that $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{A}$, since there is a bijection $f: A \rightarrow A$ satisfying all the conditions above.